# Sqoop export from Hive to MySQL fails for emojis only

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop, emoji

We are doing a sqoop export into MySQL from Hive. While the import works fine for all the records, it fails when there is a emoji in the record. However, if i manually insert the record with emoji into MySQL, it works. This has something to do with the character set UTF8MB4. MySQL table is set to UTF8MB4 and database also has the same character set. Please suggest a solution

The following command fails for emoji when we try and export.

sqoop export --connect "jdbc:mysql://ABCD.mysql.database.azure.com/ABCD_preprod" --username 'mysqladmin@XXXX' --password xxxxxx --table testtable --hcatalog-database test_db -hcatalog-table testtable --input-fields-terminated-by , --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver